# Django on Heroku, url template tag causes 'ParseResult' object not callable

Tags: django, heroku

Does anyone know what Heroku changes on deploy?  I've got a local dev machine setup with Ubuntu 11.10, and my project installed into a venv, all packages managed via pip.  The corresponding requirements.txt is in my repo, and is sent to Heroku on push.  Both my local machine and Heroku are accessing the same RDS instance on AWS.

Running the Django dev server locally (manage.py runserver) results in a working page.  Attempting to run (via my Procfile) the dev server on Heroku causes an error in the template at {% url foobar %} as follows:

```
Caught TypeError while rendering: 'ParseResult' object is not callable
```

My requirements.txt contains the following:

```
Django==1.3.1
MySQL-python==1.2.3
PIL==1.1.7
amqplib==1.0.2
anyjson==0.3.1
boto==2.2.2
celery==2.5.1
distribute==0.6.24
django-celery==2.5.1
django-kombu==0.9.4
django-picklefield==0.2.0
django-piston==0.2.3
gevent==0.13.6
greenlet==0.3.4
gunicorn==0.14.2
httplib2==0.7.4
kombu==2.1.1
python-dateutil==1.5
wsgiref==0.1.2
zencoder==0.4
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem (actually in the urls.py, not in the template rendering) while using django-piston.  I managed to fix it by changing

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url
```

to

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url as django_url
```

and then changing all the url() directives in urlpatterns to django_url().

This also fixed up the template thing I was seeing in admin pages.  I'm not sure if this is the same thing, but might be a fruitful inquiry.

Comment: Wow.  You are awesome sir.  Couldn't figure out for the longest time what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm afraid I can't offer much insight into your issue, with regard to the question "Does anyone know what Heroku changes on deploy?", then for Django apps, it's just the following:

#### [Heroku DB config appended to your settings.py](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/django#L8)

This just overrides your existing `DATABASES` setting by pulling in the `DATABASE_URL` in the environment and parsing it accordingly.

#### [Basic Procfile autogenerated if you don't already have one](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/release#L30)

Don't rely on this, as the generated `Procfile` just uses the Django development server (replace it with e.g. [one running gunicorn](http://www.askthepony.com/blog/2011/07/getting-django-on-heroku-prancing-8-times-faster/)), but it's all you need to get a basic project started.

#### [5MB (free) shared database added](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/release#L27)

This just ensures your app will have a database to access.

---

Now, I don't see how any of those would cause the problem you experience, but [you seem to have that sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9797652/928098) which is good.